# Testing removal of django whitenoise

Tags: django, cdn, whitenoise

In my django microservice, I have copied some of the whitenoise related code along with other code which I don't need because it should get handled at the CDN level. I have removed `"whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware"` from the settings.py but I'm not sure how to check if I need to remove anything else. In simple words, how do I check if my microservice is using whitenoise or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your logs. If you see some urls for your static files, then it means your microservice serves static files.

Comment: I still have /static urls but the UI is not the way I expect it to be. How can I fix this?